# Conditional Selection of Alphabet Letters

Tags: combinatorics

How many $5$-letter words are in a $26$-letter alphabet in which the letter $A$ appears but is not the initial letter of the word?

**Attempt:** If $A$ cannot be chosen as the first letter of a word, then we have $25$ possibilities for the first letter. Since we comply with the condition, we will have $4$ chances of $A$ appearing at least once after the first letter. For the other letters we will have $26$ possibilities, therefore:

$$25 \cdot 4 \cdot 26^3 = 1757600$$

The answer to the question is $1658775$. I would like to know what is my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've double-counted some cases - the factor of 4 gives you 4 places where you put the A, but then the factor of $26^3$ includes the possibility that A is one of the other 3 letters, which means that patterns like ?A??A are being counted as both "A in 2nd place, 5th letter is free" and "A in 5th place, 2nd letter is free".

You might find it easier to take the difference of two counts, one of which is the number of words that don't have A anywhere.

Comment: What's the problem with having more than one "A"? Letters can repeat themselves, right?

Comment: @Behemooth  There is nothing wrong with having more than one A.  In fact, the double-counting issue arises exactly because you can have multiple A's. So yes, you van have more than one A ... you just need to make sure that you count a word like SALSA just once, rather than twice ... with your calculation, you count it twice.

Comment: Maybe try a smaller version of the problem where you can explicitly list all the possibilities - set the alphabet as $\{A, B, C\}$ and look at 3-letter words, then your method will count "BAA" and "CAA" twice each, so your calculation will be 2 too many.

Comment: @ConMan Your comment enlightened me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

ConMan's answer explains the OP's mistake.  Further, as suggested by the answer of ConMan, the correct enumeration is $$25 \times \left[(26)^4 - (25)^4\right]. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, the 1st factor reflects the number of choices for the first letter.  In the 2nd factor, the 1st term reflects all possible 4 character words, while the 2nd term reflects all possible 4 character words that do not use an "A".